# Subscription service or software to handle a Magazine's PDF

Tags: software, pdf, subscription

I'm looking for an installable or hosted software (service) to handle the process of public users subscribing to the Magazine and receiving the PDF automatically upon an admin upload the new one.
The system will have to:

- handle the money part (PayPal&Co. are OK)
- let user buy old issues of the Magazine
- warn user on subscription expiring, etc.

PDF stamping and WordPress integration (user credential sharing, page access of subriscrebed goods, etc) will be a big plus.

Comment: Define "WordPress integration."

Answer (score 1):

[MagCloud](http://www.magcloud.com/help/howtopublish) is a print-on-demand magazine service from HP that lets you offer digital versions of your issues. There's a potential problem in that they seem primarily focused on the print side, and it's unclear to me from their basic information if you can offer the digital versions *only*. You should be able to determine that quickly while evaluating.

Comment: I've just gave a spin to MagCloud that seems to don't handle subscription.